# Hibernate: Identifier

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, rdbms

When using Hibernate:

Must I identify an id or composite id for each entity,
What about if I want to use table without any primary key and without composite key ...

Thanx in advance

Comment: if you don't have a PK how do you update a record?

Comment: if there is an owned table that follow another owner table, then the owned table will not updated by itself, but it must updated according to the owned tuple in the owner table (using reference key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are working with a legacy schema then you need to have a look at [composite-id](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid).

Comment: Link should be http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid

Answer (score 2):

A table without a key isn't a good relational model.  I would not recommend it.

Hibernate's best practices say you should have an id.  Composite ids are workable for legacy apps, but not always the best idea.

If you really must have a table without a key, I'd suggest that you shouldn't use Hibernate.  It's an ORM tool, and it sounds like you're thinking about neither objects nor relational tables properly.  Start with JDBC.